# Mongo db first install

Tags: mongodb

I have win 10 32bit and i've installed mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.22

[image]

I have this connection problem:

```
C:\Windows\System32>mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.22
connecting to: test
2020-05-09T13:05:14.422+0300 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
2020-05-09T13:05:14.423+0300 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14
@(connect):1:6
```

exception: connect failed

As the pic....
I tryied --repair but its still doesn't work
I also checked service - but on windows the service is automaticaly running....
What should I do for connecting with mongo?

another pic:
[image]

## 3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIy0I.png)

________________________________RUN THE COMMANDS___________________________
commands: mongo

mongod status

mongod start

netstat -ano | findStr "27017

C:>mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.22
connecting to: test
2020-05-09T14:33:25.073+0300 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
2020-05-09T14:33:25.074+0300 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed

C:>mongod status
2020-05-09T23:53:50.866+0300 I CONTROL  [main]
2020-05-09T23:53:50.866+0300 W CONTROL  [main] 32-bit servers don't have journaling enabled by default. Please use --journal if you want durability.
2020-05-09T23:53:50.866+0300 I CONTROL  [main]
Invalid command: status
Options:

General options:
  -h [ --help ]                 show this usage information
  --version                     show version information
  -f [ --config ] arg           configuration file specifying additional
                                options
  -v [ --verbose ] [=arg(=v)]   be more verbose (include multiple times for
                                more verbosity e.g. -vvvvv)
  --quiet                       quieter output
  --port arg                    specify port number - 27017 by default
  --bind_ip arg                 comma separated list of ip addresses to listen
                                on - all local ips by default
  --ipv6                        enable IPv6 support (disabled by default)
  --maxConns arg                max number of simultaneous connections -
                                1000000 by default
  --logpath arg                 log file to send write to instead of stdout -
                                has to be a file, not directory
  --logappend                   append to logpath instead of over-writing
  --logRotate arg               set the log rotation behavior (rename|reopen)
  --timeStampFormat arg         Desired format for timestamps in log messages.
                                One of ctime, iso8601-utc or iso8601-local
  --pidfilepath arg             full path to pidfile (if not set, no pidfile is
                                created)
  --keyFile arg                 private key for cluster authentication
  --noauth                      run without security
  --setParameter arg            Set a configurable parameter
  --httpinterface               enable http interface
  --clusterAuthMode arg         Authentication mode used for cluster
                                authentication. Alternatives are
                                (keyFile|sendKeyFile|sendX509|x509)
  --auth                        run with security
  --jsonp                       allow JSONP access via http (has security
                                implications)
  --rest                        turn on simple rest api
  --slowms arg (=100)           value of slow for profile and console log
  --profile arg                 0=off 1=slow, 2=all
  --cpu                         periodically show cpu and iowait utilization
  --sysinfo                     print some diagnostic system information
  --noIndexBuildRetry           don't retry any index builds that were
                                interrupted by shutdown
  --noscripting                 disable scripting engine
  --notablescan                 do not allow table scans

Windows Service Control Manager options:
  --install                     install Windows service
  --remove                      remove Windows service
  --reinstall                   reinstall Windows service (equivalent to
                                --remove followed by --install)
  --serviceName arg             Windows service name
  --serviceDisplayName arg      Windows service display name
  --serviceDescription arg      Windows service description
  --serviceUser arg             account for service execution
  --servicePassword arg         password used to authenticate serviceUser

Replication options:
  --oplogSize arg               size to use (in MB) for replication op log.
                                default is 5% of disk space (i.e. large is
                                good)

Master/slave options (old; use replica sets instead):
  --master                      master mode
  --slave                       slave mode
  --source arg                  when slave: specify master as 
  --only arg                    when slave: specify a single database to
                                replicate
  --slavedelay arg              specify delay (in seconds) to be used when
                                applying master ops to slave
  --autoresync                  automatically resync if slave data is stale

Replica set options:
  --replSet arg                 arg is [/]
  --replIndexPrefetch arg       specify index prefetching behavior (if
                                secondary) [none|_id_only|all]
  --enableMajorityReadConcern   enables majority readConcern

Sharding options:
  --configsvr                   declare this is a config db of a cluster;
                                default port 27019; default dir /data/configdb
  --configsvrMode arg           Controls what config server protocol is in use.
                                When set to "sccc" keeps server in legacy
                                SyncClusterConnection mode even when the
                                service is running as a replSet
  --shardsvr                    declare this is a shard db of a cluster;
                                default port 27018

Storage options:
  --storageEngine arg           what storage engine to use - defaults to
                                wiredTiger if no data files present
  --dbpath arg                  directory for datafiles - defaults to \data\db\
                                which is C:\data\db\ based on the current
                                working drive
  --directoryperdb              each database will be stored in a separate
                                directory
  --noprealloc                  disable data file preallocation - will often
                                hurt performance
  --nssize arg (=16)            .ns file size (in MB) for new databases
  --quota                       limits each database to a certain number of
                                files (8 default)
  --quotaFiles arg              number of files allowed per db, implies --quota
  --smallfiles                  use a smaller default file size
  --syncdelay arg (=60)         seconds between disk syncs (0=never, but not
                                recommended)
  --upgrade                     upgrade db if needed
  --repair                      run repair on all dbs
  --repairpath arg              root directory for repair files - defaults to
                                dbpath
  --journal                     enable journaling
  --nojournal                   disable journaling (journaling is on by default
                                for 64 bit)
  --journalOptions arg          journal diagnostic options
  --journalCommitInterval arg   how often to group/batch commit (ms)

C:>mongod start
2020-05-09T23:54:05.428+0300 I CONTROL  [main]
2020-05-09T23:54:05.428+0300 W CONTROL  [main] 32-bit servers don't have journaling enabled by default. Please use --journal if you want durability.
2020-05-09T23:54:05.432+0300 I CONTROL  [main]
Invalid command: start
Options:

General options:
  -h [ --help ]                 show this usage information
  --version                     show version information
  -f [ --config ] arg           configuration file specifying additional
                                options
  -v [ --verbose ] [=arg(=v)]   be more verbose (include multiple times for
                                more verbosity e.g. -vvvvv)
  --quiet                       quieter output
  --port arg                    specify port number - 27017 by default
  --bind_ip arg                 comma separated list of ip addresses to listen
                                on - all local ips by default
  --ipv6                        enable IPv6 support (disabled by default)
  --maxConns arg                max number of simultaneous connections -
                                1000000 by default
  --logpath arg                 log file to send write to instead of stdout -
                                has to be a file, not directory
  --logappend                   append to logpath instead of over-writing
  --logRotate arg               set the log rotation behavior (rename|reopen)
  --timeStampFormat arg         Desired format for timestamps in log messages.
                                One of ctime, iso8601-utc or iso8601-local
  --pidfilepath arg             full path to pidfile (if not set, no pidfile is
                                created)
  --keyFile arg                 private key for cluster authentication
  --noauth                      run without security
  --setParameter arg            Set a configurable parameter
  --httpinterface               enable http interface
  --clusterAuthMode arg         Authentication mode used for cluster
                                authentication. Alternatives are
                                (keyFile|sendKeyFile|sendX509|x509)
  --auth                        run with security
  --jsonp                       allow JSONP access via http (has security
                                implications)
  --rest                        turn on simple rest api
  --slowms arg (=100)           value of slow for profile and console log
  --profile arg                 0=off 1=slow, 2=all
  --cpu                         periodically show cpu and iowait utilization
  --sysinfo                     print some diagnostic system information
  --noIndexBuildRetry           don't retry any index builds that were
                                interrupted by shutdown
  --noscripting                 disable scripting engine
  --notablescan                 do not allow table scans

Windows Service Control Manager options:
  --install                     install Windows service
  --remove                      remove Windows service
  --reinstall                   reinstall Windows service (equivalent to
                                --remove followed by --install)
  --serviceName arg             Windows service name
  --serviceDisplayName arg      Windows service display name
  --serviceDescription arg      Windows service description
  --serviceUser arg             account for service execution
  --servicePassword arg         password used to authenticate serviceUser

Replication options:
  --oplogSize arg               size to use (in MB) for replication op log.
                                default is 5% of disk space (i.e. large is
                                good)

Master/slave options (old; use replica sets instead):
  --master                      master mode
  --slave                       slave mode
  --source arg                  when slave: specify master as 
  --only arg                    when slave: specify a single database to
                                replicate
  --slavedelay arg              specify delay (in seconds) to be used when
                                applying master ops to slave
  --autoresync                  automatically resync if slave data is stale

Replica set options:
  --replSet arg                 arg is [/]
  --replIndexPrefetch arg       specify index prefetching behavior (if
                                secondary) [none|_id_only|all]
  --enableMajorityReadConcern   enables majority readConcern

Sharding options:
  --configsvr                   declare this is a config db of a cluster;
                                default port 27019; default dir /data/configdb
  --configsvrMode arg           Controls what config server protocol is in use.
                                When set to "sccc" keeps server in legacy
                                SyncClusterConnection mode even when the
                                service is running as a replSet
  --shardsvr                    declare this is a shard db of a cluster;
                                default port 27018

Storage options:
  --storageEngine arg           what storage engine to use - defaults to
                                wiredTiger if no data files present
  --dbpath arg                  directory for datafiles - defaults to \data\db\
                                which is C:\data\db\ based on the current
                                working drive
  --directoryperdb              each database will be stored in a separate
                                directory
  --noprealloc                  disable data file preallocation - will often
                                hurt performance
  --nssize arg (=16)            .ns file size (in MB) for new databases
  --quota                       limits each database to a certain number of
                                files (8 default)
  --quotaFiles arg              number of files allowed per db, implies --quota
  --smallfiles                  use a smaller default file size
  --syncdelay arg (=60)         seconds between disk syncs (0=never, but not
                                recommended)
  --upgrade                     upgrade db if needed
  --repair                      run repair on all dbs
  --repairpath arg              root directory for repair files - defaults to
                                dbpath
  --journal                     enable journaling
  --nojournal                   disable journaling (journaling is on by default
                                for 64 bit)
  --journalOptions arg          journal diagnostic options
  --journalCommitInterval arg   how often to group/batch commit (ms)

C:>netstat -ano | findStr "27017

C:>

---

Comment: Please don't use screenshot to share your code or logs, copy it directly in your question.

Comment: ok thank you i'll try that(: im a rookie(:

Answer (score 0):

mongod --storageEngine=mmapv1

This command fixed the problem(:

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your mongodb.cfg setting. Just comment out the last line mp  (#mp) and try to restart the mongod.

Hope this helps.